# addListener not working with multiple markers

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to assign addListeners to individual markers where there are multiple markers and it is not working. What is happening is that all the windows are opening at once, even when I don't click. And when I do click, nothing happens. What is wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDUE08r9kD1p5QsqOzmI6_EcoUNCJntf5I&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //start the map. code from google maps tutorial.
    function initialize() { 
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7750, -122.4183),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        //return a map for later use
        return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions); 
    }

    function request() {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "stations.php",
            data: {
                route: $("#route").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var routePathCoords = [];
                var pathColor = data.color; 

                $.each(data.stations, function(i,j) {
                    routePathCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat[i], data.longit[i]));

                });

                //create new map
                var map = initialize();

                //generating the polyline
                var routePath = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
                    path: routePathCoords,
                    strokeColor: pathColor,
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 5
                });

                routePath.setMap(map);

                //creating each marker, display on screen
                $.each(routePathCoords, function(i,c) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        //obtaining from coordinates array
                        position: c, 
                        map: map,
                        //obtaining from stations array
                        title: data.stations[i] 
                    });

                    var name = marker.title;
                    //listen for click, then activate window
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', stnWindow(name, marker, map));

                });

            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log(ajaxOptions);
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }    
        });
        return false;
    }

    function stnWindow(name, marker, map) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "window.php",
            data: {
                name: name
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //initializing variables for window+content
                var station = data.fullname;
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                //adding station title
                var content = "<h1>" + station + "</h1>";
                //get names and times, put into var content
                $.each(data.destns, function(i,n) {
                    content = content + "<h2> Destination: </h2>" + n;
                    content = content + "<h3> Arrival: </h3>" + data.arrivals[i] + "minutes" ;

                });
                infoWindow.setContent(content);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the `stnWindow` function instead of assigning it.

You could solve it by returning a function containing only the ajax call, like this:

```
function stnWindow (name, marker, map) {
  return function () {
    $.ajax() //...
  }
}
```

That will not trigger the returned function until the click is fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to replace :   
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', stnWindow(name, marker, map));  
by :  
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){  
  $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        dataType: "json",  
        url: "window.php",  
        data: {  
            name: name  
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            //initializing variables for window+content  
            var station = data.fullname;  
            ....
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }  
    })  
});
```

Comment: Ouch! That might mess up variable references.

Comment: I don't think there is problem with references, thanks to javascript closures:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: How closures works is the reason there could be problems. Since google.maps.event.addListener() is called from inside a $.each() at least the variables `marker` and `name` might be in trouble. In vanilla JavaScript they would be referring to the wrong values, not sure how much magic jQuery adds to the mix though.